# How to upload image using selenium webdriver (Mac)

Tags: selenium

Unable to Upload image using selenium web driver in MAC

HTML content having a button "choose Photo", on clicking it upload window will be opened.

AS code doesn't have an input type as file I couldn't use Send Keys .

I have tried the Robot class, but it has the constraint that we couldn't run in the background.

Kindly suggest the methods can be used on MAC .(Am able to successfully upload using AutoIT in windows)

Thanks
Kavitha S

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `choose Photo` button will make us interact with the desktop, `Selenium` works on web-based applications. `AutoIt` can work well because it is intended for desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Frian answer that selenium web driver only works on the browser. However, from my understand I’m not sure if AutoIt is compatible with Mac you may have to use an alternative. You can find a list of alternatives here - alternativeto.net/software/autoit/?platform=mac